# boost ptr_vector iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, tree, ptr-vector

I am iterating through the children of a tree node. The children are stored in a ptr_vector, and at some point throughout the iteration I fall into infinite recursion, but I cannot figure out why.

Here is the method where the infinite recursion occurs (this method is just used to print the tree structure into `cout`):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const node &n) {
    if (n.children_.empty())
        return strm << "[]";

    for (boost::ptr_vector<node::edge>::const_iterator iter = n.children_.begin(); iter != n.children_.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (iter != n.children_.begin())
            strm << ", ";
        strm << "-" << iter->distance << "->[ " << *(iter->dest) << "]";
    }

    return strm;
}
```

And here is the tree structure I am navigating (note that the purpose of the nested `edge` is to represent distance between parent and child nodes):

```
class node
{
public:
    node(void);
    ~node(void);

    node* add_child(unsigned int d);
    node* get_closest(void);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const node&);

private:
    class edge
    {
    public:
        edge(node* n, unsigned int d);
        ~edge(void);

        unsigned int distance;
        node* dest;
    };

    boost::ptr_vector<edge> children_;
};
```

Additionally, I noticed that this infinite recursion occurs only after the following method has been called:

```
node* node::get_closest(void) const
{
    if (children_.empty())
        return NULL;

    boost::ptr_vector<node::edge>::const_iterator iter = children_.begin();
    node::edge closest = *iter;
    ++iter;

    if (iter != children_.end())
    {
        for (; iter != children_.end(); ++iter)
        {
            if (iter->distance < closest.distance)
                closest = *iter;
        }
    }

    return closest.dest;
}
```

Why does this method cause infinite recursion?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your tree is likely to contain a cycle...

Comment: @RobI That's very true, but I am using a test case in which I have a node with two children.

Comment: do the two children both have edges between each other? '<< *(iter->dest)' might be calling itself with a node that always has at least a child

Comment: Nop they both don't have any edges.

Comment: OK, good point.  Any possible issues with the mix of raw and shared pointers?  Like an intentional shallow copy?  Look at that `node::edge closest = *iter;`.

Comment: @RobI Should `closest`be a `node::edge*`? (If so, this doesn't work: `node::edge* closest = iter` - so what is the proper way to initialize `closest`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with @RobI's suggestion, there mixture of raw and shared pointers is causing the problem.
I changed `node::edge closest = *iter;` to `const node::edge* closest = &(*iter);`. Here is the new (and working) version of the method:

```
node* node::get_closest(void) const
{
    if (children_.empty())
        return NULL;

    boost::ptr_vector<node::edge>::const_iterator iter = children_.begin();
    const node::edge* closest = &(*iter);
    ++iter;

    if (iter != children_.end())
    {
        for (; iter != children_.end(); ++iter)
        {
            if (iter->distance < closest->distance)
                closest = &(*iter);
        }
    }

    return closest->dest;
}
```

Comment: Glad it's working, but the `&(*iter)` are a red flag - you should definitely try something more like `boost::shared_ptr<node::edge> closest = *iter;` instead.

Comment: @RobI Why is `&(*iter)` a red flag?

Comment: Well first of all, use of `&` is usually pretty rare for me.  Second, dereferencing the iterator should give you a reference to the object the shared pointer points to, so taking the address of that gives you a raw pointer to the object, when there are also smart pointers to it, which raises the risk of introducing bugs...

Comment: @RobI: I believe `boost::shared_ptr<node::edge> closest = *iter;` is much worse. That would give you two sets of smart pointers that ultimately point to the same object. When the `shared_ptr` goes away, the object will be destroyed even though it's still in the `ptr_vector`. (But this would be correct if this was a `vector< shared_ptr<node::edge> >`.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: OK, I'm a boost newbie at best so I did some digging.  I now believe *iter gives a _reference_, not another smart pointer, so you couldn't assign it to a `shared_ptr` this way (compile error).  That explains why the OP's code works, and my recommendation is wrong, but I'd still rather assign to a local reference rather than a local pointer, myself.